# Is it a bad idea to keep laptop suspended most of the time?

Tags: laptop, sleep, hibernate, suspend, power-consumption

I have an old netbook (Acer Aspire One 531h) which I am planning on setting up as a Xubuntu powered Plex client for my parents. They will control it using the android Plex app and a WoL utility for power-on.

However waking up from hibernation takes a little longer than I would like and I was wondering if it was a bad idea (power-consumption-wise) to keep the little guy suspended most of the time instead.

The battery is long dead and disposed of.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to try and **avoid** an answer based on my opinion. The facts are:

1. In standby, the computer still consumes power. You have to pay for that power.
2. Hardware components that are powered generate heat and age. After years, they will reach the end of life. The battery suffers the most, but you say that is no longer an issue.

Comment: My understanding of suspend is that only RAM and some basic circuitry required to power on the rest of the machine is kept powered. With that in mind,h ow much power can a static DDR2 laptop RAM require to keep its data? I assume that it could very well be within the margin of the standby power consumed by the adapter itself. Wear and tear is a non issue here as this is obsolete hardware that would otherwise gather dust.